# Viewing images inside messages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a system with a stereo camera, and would like to group left/right image pairs together as soon as possible, to reduce desynchronization due to asynchronous exchanges. It results that my messages are not Image themselves, but containing 2 Image. Is there a way to easily see images inside any kind of message ? Ideally something like rqt_image_view, but able to peek inside topic messages fields, rather than just show those that are of top-level type Image ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247283/viewing-images-inside-messages/) by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
Not an answer, just curious:

> [..] as soon as possible, to reduce desynchronization due to asynchronous exchanges

is there something in your system that makes using `header.stamp` for this not possible? It is explicitly meant to synchronise msgs.

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2016-11-05**:
Synchronizing messages based on a timestamp would be much harder than just receiving pairs that I know by design have been generated together. The images are correlated at the source, I see as wasteful separating them, then doing additional efforts to re-correlate them.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
Synchronising subscriptions is built-in into the middleware (see [wiki/message_filters - Policy-based Synchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D). Using separate dataflows allows you to re-use existing msg defs, in this case Images and ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
.. `CameraInfo` data.

I'm not claiming that what you're doing is wrong btw, just curious.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
Subscribing to a field inside a msg is not universally supported. `rostopic echo ..` can do it. The `relay_field` command in the `topic_tools` pkg can also do it. It can then also republish the field to another topic. That would allow you to use `image_view` to view the extracted image.

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2016-11-05**:
The synchro middleware looks cool, especially to sync separated sources, but in my case I think it would be adding unneeded complexity. Plus I'd like to annotate the images with custom fields, so that would make a lot of things to synchronize, just for the sake of having pure Image messages.

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2016-11-05**:
I managed to use echo, but am struggling with relay_field. (I saw your question about it on github, thanks for digging !). I think it's not very practical, from the looks of it: you'd have to explicit every single field of the Image you want to produce, it seems (and even that I didn't manage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually it works with simply `topic_tools transform`:

```
$ rosmsg show stereo_camera/RectifiedPair
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
sensor_msgs/Image left
...

$ rosrun topic_tools transform /rectified_pair /rect_left sensor_msgs/Image
```

I'm not sure `relay_field` is necessary anymore. At least in my case, `transform` can relay simply enough.

---

Originally posted by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) with karma: 20 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-10**:
Nice. Good to hear it worked for you.

And thanks for reporting back.

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2016-11-10**:
Thanks for formatting my answer :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-11**:
No problem :).